# SlowCheetah - Copy transformed file to output folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, slowcheetah

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 project I have a folder "Config" with some config files including SlowCheetah transformations. I want to include this (transformed) files in my web.config using the configSource attribute:

```
<someElement configSource="Config\myconfigfile.properties" />
```

Unfortunately this inclusion only works if I set "Copy to output directory" for my partial config file and include the config file this way:

```
<someElement configSource="bin\Config\myconfigfile.properties" />
```

The original file in the Config folder is transformed on build, but the copied file in the bin\Config folder is the original file without the transformation. Is there any solution for this scenario?

Comment: This was working before. Can u open an issue https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah? I can investigate it.

Comment: Thank you Sayed, I opened an issue: https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/issues/171

Comment: FYI I haven't forgotten about this. I've been on vacation and have been busy with family so haven't had a chance to investigate. It's on my radar for next week when I get back from vacation.